# A subgroup of the $n$-Selmer group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, number-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime and for the purpose of this question let $n$ be an integer which is a power of $p$.
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $F$.
The $n$-Selmer group, denoted by $S_n(E/F)$, is the subgroup of cohomology classes $[c]$ in $H^1(F, E[n])$ such that $[c_v]$ lies in the image of $\kappa_v: E(F_v)/n \hookrightarrow H^1(F_v, E[n])$, for every place $v$ of $F$.

When $n$ is a power of $p$, I believe it should be possible that cohomology classes $[c]$ in $H^1(F, E[n])$ map to (non-trivial) $[c_v]$ which lie in the image of a *proper subgroup* of $E(F_v)/n$ under $\kappa_v$ for all $v$.
The subgroup of all such $[c]$ would be a subgroup of $S_n(E/F)$. Has such an object been studied in literature?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is the "proper subgroup" fixed? Then yes there are plenty of examples, like +- Selmer groups etc. Otherwise if you mean that $[c_v]$ is not a generator of $E(F_v)/n$ then the set of these $[c]$ isn't always a subgroup of Selmer.

Comment: For example, if $n=p^k$ then is it possible that $[c_v]$ all lie in the image of $E(F_v)/p^{k-1}$?

Comment: That sounds like a group that compares with the image of the $p^{k-1}$-Selmer group in the $p^k$-Selmer group or $[p] S_{p^k}(E/F)$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich yes, this subgroup (call it $S$) is such that $S_{p^{k-1}} \subseteq S \subseteq S_{p^k}$. In general, should $S$ be distinct from either of the two?